# awk or bash to read IDs from CSV, match rows in second CSV, change value in 2nd column

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have two .csv

items-to-change.txt is a  single column list of unique ids:

```
218294
222084
197931
198161
197432
201021
214009
```

items-by-location.txt has unique ids and location number (tab delimited)

```
ID  Location
197432  1
201021  2
214009  4
214438  5
214492  1
...
```

I need to change the location field in items-by-location.txt to 6 for any ID from  matches an ID in the items-to-change.txt, then create a new .csv from this, such as items-by-location2.txt

items-by-location2.txt should be:

```
197432  6
201021  6
214009  6
214438  5
214492  1
...
```

Is awk is a good solution for this? I understand that awk has a search parameter, but it is not clear how I would use awk to read through items-to-change.txt get the ID then read line by line the items-by-location.txt, compare the ids and only 2nd column of items-by-location.txt if there is a matching ID in 1st column.

Can someone provide an example?

Comment: `awk` would work well for this.  You can go either by the `FILENAME` internal variable, or use the old `NR == FNR` / `NR != FNR` trick to run different code based on which file you're parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the change list into an array, and then checking that array when processing the main input file is perfect for `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FILENAME=="changeset" { replace[$1] = 1 } FILENAME=="input" {if( $1 in replace ) { $2 = 6 }; print $1,$2}' changeset input
ID Location
197432 6
201021 6
214009 6
214438 5
214492 1
```

Comment: I wonder how many times this `awk` code (or similar ones) have been written in answers on this site...

Comment: I'd guess at least once or thrice.